# What equivalent can replace C# InputStream.Position in Java InputStream?

Tags: java, c#, inputstream

I have the source code of a C# program for converting files. I need to write a Java application with the same functionality. But I'm having problems with the (InputStream.Position). For example:

```
//Open Files
                FileStream input = new FileStream(ltcFile, FileMode.Open);
                FileStream output = new FileStream(txtFile, FileMode.Create);

                //Skip LTC Header
                const int LTC_HEADER_LENGTH = 8;
                input.Position = input.Position + LTC_HEADER_LENGTH;

                //Write Unicode Text Header
                output.WriteByte(0xEF);
                output.WriteByte(0xBB);
                output.WriteByte(0xBF);

                //Get Data Size
                int b, dataSize;
                dataSize = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                {
                    b = input.ReadByte();
                    dataSize = dataSize + b * (int)System.Math.Pow(256, i);
                }

                //Set ID Table Position
                long idPos = dataSize + LTC_HEADER_LENGTH + 4;

                //Skip Unknown Data
                input.Position = input.Position + 4;
```

What equivalent in Java can achieve this(`mark(), skip()`)?:

```
//Skip Unknown Data
                input.Position = input.Position + 4;
```

Comment: Slightly unrelated: it's much easier not to "convert" 1:1 but to extract the requirements from the existing code and implement those in the desired language regardless of how it has been done in the original.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`InputStream.skip(long n)` is probably what you're looking for, per [the JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#skip(long)) it skips over the next `n` bytes of the stream.